# typeof(T) when T is dynamically created is null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

I have need to create a type dynamically (T) and call a generic method with parameter IQueryable. Like this:

```
Type dynamicType = LinqRuntimeTypeBuilder.GetDynamicType(newProps); // newProps is Dictionary<string, Type>
MethodInfo getData = typeof(Helpers).GetMethod("GetData", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
getData = getData.MakeGenericMethod(dynamicType);

MethodInfo exec = typeof(ObjectContext).GetMethod("ExecuteStoreQuery", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(object[]) });
exec = exec.MakeGenericMethod(dynamicType);

MethodInfo qyble = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "AsQueryable").ToList()[0];
qyble = qyble.MakeGenericMethod(dynamicType);

var q1 = exec.Invoke(db, new object[] { "SELECT Id FROM SomeTable", new object[] { } });
q1 = qyble.Invoke(null, new object[] { q1 });

getData.Invoke(null, new object[] { q1 }));
```

Now, when in method:

```
public static object GetData<T>(IQueryable<T> data)
{
    Type t = typeof(T); // This gives me null;
}
```

typeof(T) is always null;

Is it the way it is supposed to be? If that is the case, can I somehow retreive type some other way?

Or I am doing someting wrong, and missing something that is presumed?

Regards,
Milos

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745853/why-would-typeoffoo-ever-return-null

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497570/typeoft-may-return-null

Comment: I see... It's by design. I was afraid of that... But I should be able to get generic arguments from data, even if T is dynamically created?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10887653/47589

Comment: @MilosMijatovic: since `typeof(T)` is a compile time operator, perhaps `data.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First()` would work for the `IQueryable<T> data`?

Comment: For `IQueryable<T>` (actually `IQueryable`) you could use `ElementType` property.

Comment: @Groo: Yes, thats the way I tried, and it works, thanks. But I cant't help but feel bad that typeof(T) not working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `typeof(T)` is a compile time operator, it unfortunately returns `null` when used with dynamically created types.

To get the runtime type for the generic parameter, this should still work:

```
public static object GetData<T>(IQueryable<T> data)
{
    Type t = data.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
    ...
}
```